# how to generate a random real number (10.0) without using the random.uniform in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the price as a real number (e.g. 10.0). I tried defining price as `price=0.0`, but I still get `10` instead of `10.0`. I also tried using random.uniform, but that gives me a very high-precision value (e.g. 2.6680527003696723). How can I get a number like x.0? (note: I want 0 always after the decimal point.)

```
import random
price=0.0
for count in range(5):  
    price=random.uniform(1.0, 100.0)
    print(price)
    price=random.randint(1.0, 100.0)
    print(price)
```

Comment: Create an integer and convert it to a float.

Comment: `price=float(random.randint(1.0, 100.0))`

Comment: Is `round(x)` OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include 100, in the range, you need an upper limit just above:

```
import random

for count in range(5):
    price = float(random.randrange(1, 101))
    print (price)
```

Output:

```
6.0
10.0
6.0
10.0
3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 float(random.randint(1,100))
```

if you want the decimal point you should cast it to float or you can use floor function with uniform

```
math.floor(random.uniform(1,100))
```

Comment: What does this add to previous answers and comments?

Comment: we almost answered at the same time i was'nt aware of the previus answer if needed i can delete my answer @Prune

Comment: Oh ... I hadn't noticed the time lag on my posting.  Never mind, you're okay.